# SQL how to get indent string of relation of parent and child in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[security_templates_exceptions_item](
    [objectid] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [moduleid] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [type] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [viewname] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [itemid] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [misc] [nchar](30) NULL,
    [menuid] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [priority] [smallint] NOT NULL,
 )
```

This table has relations to childs itself.

So the logic is easy.

`priority` has the following values:

```
10
20
30
40
```

All digits ending in 0 like 10, 20, and so on are the parents.

If I have

```
10
11
12
13
```

Then I know that 11,12 and 13 are children of `10`.

Following this logic I want to indent a string with the `objectid` column.

Here is a SQL Fiddle with the schema and sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dc15/1

So if I have the following data:

[image]

I should get this format (look at objectid indentation):

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dc15/9/0

You can concatenate objectid with spaces or whatever else where view_name is not null.

```
select   case when viewname is null then objectid else '......'+objectid end as objectid,
         description,
         priority
from     security_templates_exceptions_item
order by menuid, priority
```